# Performance detriment of social media buttons

Tags: performance, social-buttons

I looked into adding the ability to:

1. Like (Facebook)
2. Share (Facebook)
3. Tweet (Twitter)
4. Share (Google+)

On the product page. To do so, I used the code snippets available directly from each of the social media platforms developer consoles, namely:

- [Like / Share Button - Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button)
- [Tweet - Twitter](https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons)
- [Share - Google +](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/)

repsectively.

I believed that this would be the most minimalistic approach to adding support for social media (as opposed to installing an extension to do so). The result though was not pleasing. :-/

**Before:**

- Page load time: 1.96s
- Total page size: 233KB
- Total number of requests: 34

**After:**

- Page load time: 3.02s
- Total page size: 783KB
- Total number of requests: 50

Using http://gtmetrix.com/ to analyze performance. That's horrific! Am I approaching this badly? Would appreciate some input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing quite a lot of research I came to the following conclusions:

### Pitfalls of social share buttons

- Dependent on Javascript
- Downloads 3rd party resources
- Adds additional http requests
- Adds additional page weight

### 1. Directly from the developer

If you access any of the links I mentioned in the question (i.e the developer zone for Facebook/Twitter/Google+), these share buttons with the counter mechanism fall to all of the aforementioned pitfalls.

### 2. Custom lightweight buttons

I decided to go with custom buttons I designed for myself using simple CSS/HTML, no JS. I merged the buttons using splicing techniques and ended up adding about 3KB to my page size and a single request.

- **Facebook:** https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=_YOUR_URL
- **Google+:** https://plus.google.com/share?url=_YOUR_URL
- **Twitter:** http://twitter.com/home/?status=_YOUR_URL

You can also add text, hashtags, mentions etc. Simple read the developer information from the social media suites directly & you'll be good to go.

The counter method (i.e seeing how many people share a page) unfortunately is not possible with static links like this, you will need some JS on the page & that's something I for one am willing to give up for sake of performance.